# Secuencia dentro de un vector en R studio

Tags: array, r, funciones, rstudio

Tengo un vector `s` de una secuencia de números y tengo que buscar en otro vector `v` con igual o mayor cantidad de elementos. La secuencia dada por `s` y la salida será el número del orden de él/los elementos en los que comienza la secuencia buscada.

Lo que logré hacer es:

```r
comparo_vectores = function(v,w){
    rta = 0

    for(i in 1:length(v)){
        if(v[i] == w[i]) {
            rta = T
        }else {
            rta = F
        }
    }

    return(rta)
}

secuencia = function(s,v) {
    w = c()

    for(i in 1:length(v) - 1) {
        if(comparo_vectores(s,v[i]) == 1) {
            w[i] = i
        }
    }

    return(w)
}
```

Pero me sale este error:

```
Error in if (v[i] == w[i]) { :
Valor ausente donde TRUE/FALSE es necesario
```

¿Alguien se le ocurre alguna otra manera de realizar la función secuencia?, o ¿sabe cuál es mi error?

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que quieres comparar dos vectores en función de la posición de los elementos y que necesitas que como salida te de el número de la posición de los elementos faltantes. (Si no es así, te sugiero que redactes un poco mejor tu pregunta).

Si entendí bien esto puede ayudar:

Tienes tus dos vectores:

```
s <- rep(1:100, times = 2)
s2 <- sample(s, 150)
```

Lo que necesitas hacer es ordenarlos:

```
ord1 <- sort(s)
ord2 <- sort(s2)
```

Función de comparación:

```
compare_fun <- function (v1, v2){ 
 
   for (i in 1:length(v1)){
  j <- match(v1[i], v2) 
  if(!is.na(j)){
    v1[i] <- NA
    v2[j] <- NA 
    }
  }
  print(v1[complete.cases(v1)]) 
}
```

Llamas la función:

```
compare_fun(ord1, ord2)
```

Y como dije, de output te saldrán el número de la posición de los elementos faltantes.

```
[1]  2  6  7  8  9 10 11 19 20 21 22 22 23 26 27 29 30 32 32 38 39 39 41 41 42 43 44 45 46 49 50 53
[33] 54 55 58 58 60 64 65 67 67 74 77 81 85 88 89 95 97 99
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es ubicar el comienzo de cierta secuencia (`s`) o patrón en un vector (`v`), la forma clásica es ir avanzando de a una posición en `v` y comparar el bloque de elementos contiguos de la longitud de `s`, si todos lo elementos coinciden, ciertamente hemos encontrado el patrón y ya tenemos su posición:

```
seq_in_vector <- function(s, v) {
  lv <- length(v)
  ls <- length(s)
  found <- c()
  j <- 1
  for (i in 1:(lv-ls+1)) {
    if (all(s == v[i:(i+ls-1)])) {
      found[j] <- i
      j <- j + 1
    }
  }
  found
}
```

Por ejemplo:

```
s <- c(1,2,3)
v <- c(4,5,6,1,2,3,7,8,9,1,2,3,4)

seq_in_vector(s, v)

[1]  4 10
```

Comment: gracias, pero por alguna razon, al correrlo me trae las posiciones de los vectores pero ademas trae la posicion 1 y la ultima posicion por mas que  no coincidan con la secuencia

Comment: Comparte un ejemplo para verificarlo, sino va a ser difícil  responder tu comentario. Saludos.

Comment: considerando
s=c(2,7,5)
v=c(3,4,5,2,7,5,7,2,7,5,3,5)

Comment: Lo acabo de probar con tu ejemplo y funciona correctamente `[1] 4 8`, ubica el patrón en la posición 4 y 8